# Where is the syntax error in this piece of sql code I wrote in themysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, rdbms, mysql-error-1064

This is a very simple piece of code using which I am trying to create a table of an entity Bank.

```
create table bank (
banknum integer(5) NOT NULL,
bankname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
primary key(banknum));
```

However, executing this gives an error:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'create table bank ( banknum integer(5) NOT NULL,
>   bankname varchar(20) NOT NULL, ' at line 1

I do not understand where this syntax error is occurring.

Comment: Is there code before this that needs a line delimiter?  Do you have a database selected?

Comment: What happens just before 'create'?

Answer (score -1):

```
create table bank (
banknum INT(5) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
bankname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: This provides no explanation for the syntax error which is the basis for this question.